# Why is the following ReactJS code resulting in infinite re-render loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The following code intends to run useEffect whenever the __payload changes.

```
const Viewer = (props) => { 
    
        const __payload = JSON.parse(props.payload);    
        const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
        
        useEffect( () => { 
            var __values = "value"; // passing in a sad string
            setValues(__values);
        }, [__payload]);
    };
```

The issue arises when I pass an array value to setValues:

```
const Viewer = (props) => { 
    
        const __payload = JSON.parse(props.payload);    
        const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
        
        useEffect( () => { 
            var __values = ["value"]; // passing in a needed array
            setValues(__values);
        }, [__payload]);
    };
```

This results in an infinite loop and an error:

```
Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
```

Why is that? The useEffect is specifically limited to run on a change to __payload variable.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call JSON.parse you get a 'new' object, even if it looks the same. From the perspective of React, every time you render `__payload` has changed, causing `setValues` to be called, causing another render.

Based on the code you shared, the easiest fix is probably changing the `useEffect` dependency to use `props.payload` instead of `__payload`.

```
    useEffect( () => { 
        var __values = "value"; // passing in a sad string
        setValues(__values);
    }, [props.payload]);
```